# Transitive test/provided dependency is included in my project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, apache-tika

Can somebody explain what is happening here? My project has a `compile` dependency on *vorbis-java-tika* (via *tika-parsers*), which in turn has a `test,provided` dependency on *vorbis-java-core:tests*

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-tika:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:tests:0.1:test,provided
```

I think that transitive `test` or `provided` dependencies of `compile` scope dependencies should not be included (at list it's my understanding of [this table](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope))

---

If it's helpful here is relevant `dependency:list` output

```
$ mvn dependency:list | grep vorbis
[INFO]    org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO]    org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:jar:tests:0.1:test,provided
[INFO]    org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-tika:jar:0.1:compile
```

Comment: What happens if you try with Apache Tika 1.7, the latest stable version?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, so it's apparently caused by invalid `test,provided` scope value in vorbis-java-tika:0.1

Comment: @Gagravarr can you advise something else than changing *vorbis-java-core* version to 0.3? I'm stuck with current tika version for now

Comment: Vorbis Java 0.7? Frankly I'd just suggest upgrading to a newer version of everything, not supporting `test` + `provided` is an annoying issue that newer versions work around but cannot otherwise be dealt with

Comment: @Gagravarr - I'm all for upgrading things but there are considerations like QA throughput and regression. What do you mean by "not supporting test + provided"? Are you compiling your main classes against this tests jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTR the problem was caused by Apache Tika having an invalid scope `test,provided` in it's pom